How do you read post-hoc (Tukey HSD) outputs for experimental designs?
I'm currently learning about experimental designs in my statistics class, and I'm really confused about how post-hoc outputs are meant to be read.
In my homework, I ran a post-hoc/Tukey HSD test on the difference between mean delivery times among three different couriers. The test statistic that I used for this was a randomized block design. My dependent variable was the shipping time, while my categorical variables were shipment batches and couriers. When I ran the data through the Statistica software, I got a column for shipments 1-5, and a column for each {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, and {5}.
To visualize, this is what Statistica gave me. Please note that I only filled out the first two rows:



Shipment Batch
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{5}




1

0.017177
0.005775
0.94846
0.000722


2
0.017177

0.893692
0.043908
0.090739


3







4







5








Under each {1}, ... {5} (in the same header block), the mean delivery time for that particular shipment was also indicated.
I was really confused to see (what I assume to be) rows and columns that are both for shipment batches, since I was interested in testing the differences in mean delivery time among the couriers.
How come shipment was the only categorical variable that's displayed in the table? Did I run the test incorrectly?

There's a stack exchange devoted to statistics, named "cross validated". Your question probably belongs there

Hi @JonathanZ, thank you so much for this! I will post on there instead.
